# Cable with multiple identical connectors in a PSU

Tags: power-supply, terminology

Most PSUs I've seen have *multiple* copies of a connector on each branch (i.e, a Molex branch, a 4-pin PCIe branch, etc). I've taken to calling one of those cables a 'branch' or a 'strip'. Is there a commonly used term for this cable/cabling style?

Comment: "Cables" is the most commonly used term for cables.

Comment: differentiate "branches" by connector

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, but looking for a term for a specific kind of cable. combining your answer with jsotola's, we would have '4-pin Molex cable' and '15-pin SATA cable', with no reference to _multiple_ connectors. i suppose professionals simply know when referring to PSU cables that certain connectors tend to have multiple copies to a single cable?

Comment: Surely you're more interested in the connector(s) and what they can interface with than the cables leading to them?... Cables are cables, they don't have a specific function/use, but the connectors are part of a matching pair.

Comment: @Attie i am interested in a term for multiple connectors extended along a single cable - so i imagine the term will correspond to a particular form of cable. for example, a [splitter cable](https://www.amazon.com/Headphone-Splitter-Computer-Smartphone-Headset/dp/B01MQZ2023) is not the same as a [splitter](https://www.amazon.com/VCE-Adapter-Splitter-Headphone-Converter/dp/B06X3WF1ZS) (although they both perform splitting).